# Delete entire objects in JSON on the condition it doesn't include keys/values

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to delete entire objects in a JSON file on the condition that they do not include ALL keys: "transaction_date", "asset_description", "asset_type", "type" and "amount" keys.

Below is my JSON file (it's been cut for this example):

```
{
    "first_name": {
        "0": "Thomas",
        "1": "John",
    },
    "transactions": {
       "0": [
            {
                "transaction_date": "11/29/2022",
                "asset_description": "FireEye, Inc.",
                "asset_type": "Stock",
                "type": "Sale (Partial)",
                "amount": "$1,001 - $15,000"
            }
          ],
       "1": [
            {
                "scanned_pdf": true,
                "ptr_link": "https://efdsearch.senate.gov/search/view/paper/658E53E8-7C2C,
                "date_recieved": "01/30/2013"
            }
          ],
          
     }
}
```

I need to delete the entire "1" data from transactions and first_name. There are more then these two in the original file so the code needs to be universal to any amount rather than using [0], [1] etc. My code below tries to find items in "transactions" that do not include "scanned_pdf", "ptr_link" and "date_recieved" and then saves the JSON just with that updated data (my method is kind of inversed, so instead of deleting objects if it doesn't include x, it will pick up the objects that don't include y and update the JSON):

```
import json

with open("xxxtester.json", "r") as f_in:
    data = json.load(f_in)

to_delete = {"scanned_pdf", "ptr_link", "date_recieved"}

for k in data["transactions"]:
    data["transactions"][k] = [
        {kk: vv for kk, vv in d.items() if kk not in to_delete}
        for d in data["transactions"][k]]


open("xxxtester.json", "w").write(
    json.dumps(data, indent=4))
```

However, my output still shows the "1" but with empty data "{}" etc. Should I use a different method of logic towards this? Or is it possible to add code to the existing script to make it work.

below is my desired output:

```
{
    "first_name": {
        "0": "Thomas",
    },
    "transactions": {
       "0": [
            {
                "transaction_date": "11/29/2022",
                "asset_description": "FireEye, Inc.",
                "asset_type": "Stock",
                "type": "Sale (Partial)",
                "amount": "$1,001 - $15,000"
            }
          ],
      }
}
```

Comment: Your first problem is that the data you've posted in your question isn't valid JSON; there are several syntax errors.

Comment: Does each item in `transactions` consist of a single-item list? Or might there be multiple dictionaries contained in each list?

Comment: There are multiple dictionaries inside @larsks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we reverse your logic (so we're selecting items we want to keep, rather than the other way around) and add a second comprehension to filter out empty values, we end up with this:

```
import json

with open("xxxtester.json", "r") as f_in:
    data = json.load(f_in)

required = set(
    ("transaction_date", "asset_description", "asset_type", "type", "amount")
)

data["transactions"] = {
    k: [transaction for transaction in v if all(k in transaction for k in required)]
    for k, v in data['transactions'].items()
}

data["transactions"] = {
    k: v for k, v in data['transactions'].items() if v
}

# Update data["first_name"] so that it only contains keys that also exists
# in data["transactions"].
data["first_name"] = {k: v for k, v in data["first_name"].items() if k in data["transactions"]}

print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))
```

Given input like this:

```
{
    "first_name": {
        "0": "Thomas",
        "1": "John"
    },
    "transactions": {
       "0": [
            {
                "transaction_date": "11/29/2022",
                "asset_description": "FireEye, Inc.",
                "asset_type": "Stock",
                "type": "Sale (Partial)",
                "amount": "$1,001 - $15,000"
            },
            {
                "scanned_pdf": true,
                "ptr_link": "https://efdsearch.senate.gov/search/view/paper/658E53E8-7C2C",
                "date_recieved": "01/30/2013"
            }
          ],
       "1": [
            {
                "scanned_pdf": true,
                "ptr_link": "https://efdsearch.senate.gov/search/view/paper/658E53E8-7C2C",
                "date_recieved": "01/30/2013"
            }
          ]
     }
}
```

The above code produces:

```
{
    "first_name": {
        "0": "Thomas"
    },
    "transactions": {
        "0": [
            {
                "transaction_date": "11/29/2022",
                "asset_description": "FireEye, Inc.",
                "asset_type": "Stock",
                "type": "Sale (Partial)",
                "amount": "$1,001 - $15,000"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

---

The first dictionary comprehension...

```
data["transactions"] = {
    k: [transaction for transaction in v if all(k in transaction for k in required)]
    for k, v in data['transactions'].items()
}
```

...produces:

```
...
    "transactions": {
        "0": [
            {
                "transaction_date": "11/29/2022",
                "asset_description": "FireEye, Inc.",
                "asset_type": "Stock",
                "type": "Sale (Partial)",
                "amount": "$1,001 - $15,000"
            }
        ],
        "1": []
    }
...
```

The second comprehension filters out keys that have empty lists as values.

The third comprehension removes items from `data["first_name]` that don't exist in `data["transactions"]`.

Comment: Thanks. One thing though is how would you remove the data from the "first_name" as well? Based on the fact that it has no correlating items in the "transactions" object anymore.

Comment: If you only care about `data["transactions"]`, then simply discard everything else. I've updated the answer to reflect this new requirement.

Comment: No sorry, I meant so if "1" in transactions doesn't contain xyz then the "1" will be deleted from transactions and First_name. However, the "0" data for first_name doesn't change. Check the desired output at the end of my question

Comment: See my update to the question, which I believe produces the output you want.

Answer (score -1):

With this code you are going to delete the whole thing.

```
import json

with open("xxxtester.json", "r") as f_in:
    data = json.load(f_in)


with open("xxxtester.json", "w") as f:
    del data["transactions"]["1"]
    json.dump(data, f)
```

Comment: I believe the goal here is to *conditionally* delete items based on their contents.